# What conditions for the Kan extension of a functor along $y$ to be full and faithful?

Tags: category-theory

Given some functor $F: A \to B$, what equivalent conditions makes the left Kan extension $\operatorname{Lan}_yF: \hat{A} \to B$ (of $F$ along $y : A \to \hat{A}$) full and faithful?

---

(non-answer only, to kick it off)

1. If $\operatorname{Lan}_y F$ is f.f., so is $\operatorname{Lan}_y F \circ y \simeq F$ so that's necessary
2. If $B$ is *cocomplete*, there is a a right adjoint (the "nerve"), so $\operatorname{Lan}_y$ f.f. is equivalent to the unit being an isomorphism
3. That same condition on the adjoint, the nerve of the functor, has been given a name, in [Isbell conjugacy and the reflexive completion](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.08290) :

   (def 7.1) $F$ is said to be ***dense*** when its nerve $N_F = B(F =, - ) : B \to \hat{A}$ (the adjoint of $\operatorname{Lan}_y F$) is full and faithfull

   Some equivalences on that at [ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dense+functor)

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment by error. It is equivalent to $F$ being fully faithful and each object in its image [tiny](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tiny+object) relatively to the image of $F$. This means that for each $c$ in this image, $\operatorname{Hom}(c,-)$ should preserve small colimits of objects in this image. I don't know if this is enough for your purpose. There is a similar way of recognizing when $A \to B$ is an ind-completions.

Comment: Thank you !  I have to meditate on that one. My goal I to have a better, hopefully more intuitive, understanding  of this condition

Comment: What do you mean by left Kan extension? The original definition, or the so-called pointwise one?

Comment: Ah, I was saying that for the pointwise definition! I meant the following. In $\hat{A}$, objects are formal colimits of diagrams in $A$ and if you have two diagrams $(X_i)_i$ and $(Y_j)_j$, then $\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}\newcommand{\colim}{\operatorname{colim}}\Hom(\colim_iX_i,\colim_jY_j)=\lim_i \Hom(X_i,\colim_jY_j)=\lim_i\colim_j\Hom(X_i,Y_j)$. So if you can reproduce the same computation in $B$, then $\hat{A}\to B$ is fully faithful.